# Direct traffic through remote machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I have Machine A, which has internet access and has Tor running on port 9150. I have Machine B, which can't access the internet but can access Machine A via SSH. I want to run a command on Machine B (no internet machine); this command on Machine B accesses the internet. I want this command to go through Machine A port 9150. I don't have sudo access on Machine B, but I have sudo access on machine A.

How do I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

If Tor is listening on localhost only, use SSH local port forwarding from Machine B:

```
ssh user@machineA -L9150:localhost:9150
```

This will effectively bind port 9150 on Machine B to port 9150 on Machine A.

Or, if you can change the Tor daemon to listen on all interfaces on Machine A and no inbound firewall blocking this, you can ignore the SSH forwarding.

In either case, you can then use a tool such as `proxychains`, configured appropriately, to prepend your commands such that they go over Tor:

```
proxychains curl http://example.onion
```

Proxychains is likely available through your package manager, but a newer version exists on GitHub at https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng. The default configuration will try to connect to a Tor SOCKS server on localhost, but this can be changed by modifying `proxychains.conf` if necessary.